# I am trying to use ReactUIDropdown with an image prop and doing exactly as the document says but getting some error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux

Here is my code snippet,

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import ReactUIDropdown from 'react-ui-dropdown';
const data = [
  {
    id: 100,
    title: 'Centaur',
    image: 'https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/120146-200.png',
  },
];
const handleDropdownChange = (selectedItems) => {
  console.log(selectedItems);
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ReactUIDropdown
        label="Myth animals"
        initialItems={data}
        onChange={handleDropdownChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am getting the error as ,

**Error in /turbo_modules/react-ui-dropdown@0.3.4/lib/components/Items.js (76:30)
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'string')**

What am I doing wrong here as undefined is getting thrown over?

Comment: That package is 7 years old, and is using `react.PropTypes` which has been deprecated since v15.5 of react, and dropped in the v16.

Comment: Okay, I am using v16.17.0 for my project, the reason for this issue. Do we have something similar nowadays which we can use?

Comment: You could use [React Dropdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropdown)